# Using 4096*4096 background image in uinty tk2d

Tags: unity, iphone, performance

I am new to Unity and I am developing a game using unity its a 2d game i am using tk2d framework. I have a big background image(4096*4096) how can I load this background so only visible part of the background has to be rendered so it wont effect the performance. How can I achive this in unity & tk2d?

Comment: there is something called mega textures - i believe games like Rage use them - also 'The other brothers' - www.tobgame.com makes use of painted backgrounds (in unity) for their entire levels instead of tile based systems - so it is possible but may require more research

Comment: "Megatextures" is just marketing IMO. Behind the scenes there are still classic hardware limits and the bigger your textures get, the higher the costs (memory, handling times, etc.). Most of these "Megatextures" implementations simply handle all the mapping and usage while staying within the hardware's specific capabilities. Overall it's something I'd avoid on mobile platforms at all costs. Even if you've got free ressources you should probably better utilize them for something more important or leave them to save battery power.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to break up the image into multiple sections.  Probably 1024x1024 for maximum compatibility ([source](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/83179-Questions-about-maximum-texture-size-can-be-used-in-iOS)).  Then you can just place them in the  background in order.

Comment: After breaking down into 1024x1024, can i use just 8 sprites or is there any other class already exists for doing this kind of job.